# Is a thick Möbius strip genus 2?

Tags: general-topology, mobius-band

A cylinder has genus 0, but a thick cylinder has genus 1. This gets me into wondering, since a Möbius strip has genus 1, would a thick Möbius strip have genus 2? I can't quite comprehend if the cuttings along a thick Möbius strip would be a closed curve or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "thick" Möbius strip may be smoothed out into a torus, so it still has genus $1$.